How to coverage my server application (containing main.go) when running an integration test with Goland? Only the test container side looks analyzed
I have a Go project with a main.go and the managers, dao, domain types... It's my server application.
I'm launching it with "Run go build main.go with Coverage".
I have also an integration_test.go file
that interacts with that launched application, by the means of OpenApi, to challenge it.
If I run this integration_test.go with "Run integration_test.go with Coverage",
at the end, it records where the program passed in integration_test.go and its child code, only.
But what I have asked to cover on the main project isn't covered,
and everything (managers, dao...) stays labeled at 0% files, 0% coverage, there.
It's the same thing if I run main.go with coverage but run the tests without coverage.
What should I do to cover my server code?

As of go 1.20 this is possible and the GoLang team did an awesome blog post on this topic I recommend reading, however this is the gist.
# Set GOCOVERDIR env variable  
export GOCOVERDIR=cov

# create directory for results
mkdir -p $GOCOVERDIR

# run main.go with coverage enabled
go run -cover main.go

# call integration tests from another terminal
go run integration_test.go

# When integration_test.go finishes kill main.go's process ctrl+c

# display the results.  
go tool covdata percent -i=cov
    some-git.provider/some-org/some-repo/cmd/some-service    coverage: 81.2% of statements


Thanks! I managed to make it work. However its outputs are odd... I receive a managers/copy coverage: 0.2% of statements when it should be around 50% regarding the logs displayed during testing. I'm using Go 1.22.1. Maybe it's still an unstable version.

Go 1.22.2 put everything at 0.0%.

I'm not sure how to reproduce that result without example code
